# JQuery page scroll animation only work on first link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

I got this **HTML** with 3 links

```
<a href="#" class="niva3" data-target="#get1">Link 1</a> 
<a href="#" class="niva3" data-target="#get2">Link 2</a>
<a href="#" class="niva3" data-target="#get3">Link 3</a>

<div class="niva3-dolj" id="get1">[include id="1365"]</div>
<div class="niva3-dolj" id="get2">[include id="1562"]</div>
<div class="niva3-dolj" id="get3">[include id="1565"]</div>
```

When i click on link 1 the page will scroll down to the div named *niva3-dolj*. When i click on link 2 or 3 the content will not scroll down. I want it to scroll down.

And also if i doubleclick, the content will appear and disappear in seconds, any solution for that?

Here is a snippet:

```js
$('a.niva3').click(function() {
  function show(sel) {
    var el = $(sel);
    el.fadeToggle();
    $('.niva3-dolj').not(el).fadeOut('fast');
  }

  $('.niva3').removeClass('niva3-farg')
  $(this).addClass('niva3-farg');
  show($(this).data('target'));
  $('html, body').stop(true, true).delay(200).animate({
    scrollTop:$('.niva3-dolj').offset().top
  }, 'slow');
});
```

```css
.niva3 {
  color: #97bf1f;
}
    
.niva3-farg {
  color: #4d4d4d !important;
}
    
.niva3-dolj {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="niva3" data-target="#get1">Link 1</a> 
<a href="#" class="niva3" data-target="#get2">Link 2</a>
<a href="#" class="niva3" data-target="#get3">Link 3</a>

<div class="niva3-dolj" id="get1">[include id="1365"]</div>
<div class="niva3-dolj" id="get2">[include id="1562"]</div>
<div class="niva3-dolj" id="get3">[include id="1565"]</div>
```

Comment: Can you show your CSS for `.niva3-farg` please?

Comment: @JonathanLam ofc post is updated

Comment: Just FYI: `fadeOut('xfast')` - `xfast` should be `fast`.

Comment: @Legionar thanks changed that now.

Comment: Your CSS currently does not size it to have _any_ scroll whatsoever. Secondly, you are fading in/out and showing/hiding so the scroll wouldn't work, thirdly you are always scrolling to the same class which is shared by multiple elements. Mainly, what do you want to accomplish? There is no scrolling here - you are hiding/showing, so... Which do you want?

Comment: @somethinghere Im trying to make a multi-level menu like this one [link](https://goo.gl/PR9rEQ) Therefore when you press a link it should change color so you know which one is pressed, and it will show it content. If you press another link, everything should dissapar from the first link and the new content should be displayed. If you look at the website i linked to you will understand. The code works its just the scrolling that i have issues with.

Comment: What link? Also, post everything here that could help us solve the problem, maybe including the divs you are scrolling too with, say, a simulated height, just to illustrate the problem to us.

Comment: @somethinghere Yes i put a link above on my comment, its in blue. You can press on it. I will write here again https://www.microsoft.com/sv-se/mobile/support/produkt/lumia800/troubleshooter/?categories=Koder%20och%20konton,Microsoft-konto#topiclist

Comment: Please help anyone :/? Still cant figure this out. If you need me to provide anything just tell me!